# Column-wise Mapping and operations on dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes namely `df1` and `df2`. I want to perform operation on column `New_Amount_Dollar` from `df2`. Basically in `df1` I have historical currency data and I want to perform datewise operation given `Currency` and `Amount_Dollar` from `df2` to calculate the values for `New_Amount_Dollar` column in `df2`.

e.g In `df2` I have first currency as `AUD` for `Date = '01-01-2019'`, so I want to calculate `New_Amount_Dollar` value such that

`New_Amount_Dollar` = `Amount_Dollar/AUD` value from `df1`
i.e `New_Amount_Dollar = 19298/98 = 196.91`

another example where in `df2` I have third currency as `COP` for `Date = '03-01-2019`, so I want to calculate `New_Amount_Dollar` value such that

`New_Amount_Dollar = Amount_Dollar/COP` value from `df1`
i.e `New_Amount_Dollar = 5000/0.043 = 116279.06`

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', '04-01-2019','05-01-2019'],
        'AUD':[98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 97],
        'BWP':[30,31,33,32,31],
        'CAD':[0.02,0.0192,0.0196,0.0196,0.0192],
        'BND':[0.99,0.952,0.970,0.980,0.970],
        'COP':[0.05,0.047,0.043,0.047,0.045]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', '04-01-2019','05-01-2019'],
        'Currency':['AUD','AUD','COP','CAD','BND'],
        'Amount_Dollar':[19298, 19210, 5000, 200, 2300],
        'New_Amount_Dollar':[0,0,0,0,0]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

```
df1

         Date   AUD  BWP     CAD    BND    COP
0  01-01-2019  98.0   30  0.0200  0.990  0.050
1  02-01-2019  98.5   31  0.0192  0.952  0.047
2  03-01-2019  99.0   33  0.0196  0.970  0.043
3  04-01-2019  99.5   32  0.0196  0.980  0.047
4  05-01-2019  97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
```

```
df2

         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298                  0
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210                  0
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000                  0
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200                  0
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300                  0
```

Expected Result

```
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298             196.91
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210             195.02
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000          116279.06
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200           10204.08
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300            2371.13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for array and divide `Amount_Dollar` column:

```
arr = df1.set_index('Date').lookup(df2['Date'], df2['Currency'])

df2['New_Amount_Dollar'] = df2['Amount_Dollar'] /  arr
print (df2)
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298         196.918367
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210         195.025381
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000      116279.069767
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200       10204.081633
4  05-01-2019      BND           2300        2371.134021
```

But if datetimes not match, use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', 
                 '04-01-2019','05-01-2019','08-01-2019'],
        'AUD':[98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 97,100],
        'BWP':[30,31,33,32,31,20],
        'CAD':[0.02,0.0192,0.0196,0.0196,0.0192,0.2],
        'BND':[0.99,0.952,0.970,0.980,0.970,.23],
        'COP':[0.05,0.047,0.043,0.047,0.045,0.023]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'Date':['01-01-2019', '02-01-2019', '03-01-2019', '04-01-2019','07-01-2019'],
        'Currency':['AUD','AUD','COP','CAD','BND'],
        'Amount_Dollar':[19298, 19210, 5000, 200, 2300],
        'New_Amount_Dollar':[0,0,0,0,0]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2) 
print (df1)
         Date    AUD  BWP     CAD    BND    COP
0  01-01-2019   98.0   30  0.0200  0.990  0.050
1  02-01-2019   98.5   31  0.0192  0.952  0.047
2  03-01-2019   99.0   33  0.0196  0.970  0.043
3  04-01-2019   99.5   32  0.0196  0.980  0.047
4  05-01-2019   97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
5  08-01-2019  100.0   20  0.2000  0.230  0.023

print (df2)
         Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0  01-01-2019      AUD          19298                  0
1  02-01-2019      AUD          19210                  0
2  03-01-2019      COP           5000                  0
3  04-01-2019      CAD            200                  0
4  07-01-2019      BND           2300                  0
```

---

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], dayfirst=True)

print (df1.set_index('Date').asfreq('D', method='ffill'))
              AUD  BWP     CAD    BND    COP
Date                                        
2019-01-01   98.0   30  0.0200  0.990  0.050
2019-01-02   98.5   31  0.0192  0.952  0.047
2019-01-03   99.0   33  0.0196  0.970  0.043
2019-01-04   99.5   32  0.0196  0.980  0.047
2019-01-05   97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
2019-01-06   97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
2019-01-07   97.0   31  0.0192  0.970  0.045
2019-01-08  100.0   20  0.2000  0.230  0.023
```

---

```
arr = df1.set_index('Date').asfreq('D', method='ffill').lookup(df2['Date'], df2['Currency'])

df2['New_Amount_Dollar'] = df2['Amount_Dollar'] /  arr
print (df2)
        Date Currency  Amount_Dollar  New_Amount_Dollar
0 2019-01-01      AUD          19298         196.918367
1 2019-01-02      AUD          19210         195.025381
2 2019-01-03      COP           5000      116279.069767
3 2019-01-04      CAD            200       10204.081633
4 2019-01-07      BND           2300        2371.134021
```

Comment: If the 'Date' from df2 is not available in df1 and I want the previous date available value. Can you help me please.
The previous day value means latest available value(Not null) from previous day

Comment: @Maddy6 - How working `arr = df1.set_index('Date').lookup(df1['Date'], df2['Currency'])` change to `arr = df1.set_index('Date').lookup(df2['Date'], df2['Currency'])` ?

Comment: basically my problem is that if dates from df2 are not present in df1 then it should take previous date value.

Comment: @Maddy6 - yop, I try create data sample with this problem, can you check edit?

Comment: It's Working :-)